# ¿Por qué list.remove(elemento) devuelve None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo una lista y me gustaría deshacerme de un valor. Así que traté de usar `remove()`:

```
arr_copy = list(arr) # tambien intenté = arr[:] y arr.copy()
print(arr_copy, deleted_element)
new_arr = arr_copy.remove(deleted_element)
print(new_arr)
```

Sin embargo parece que me deshago de toda la lista:

```
[3, 3, 2, 1, 3] 1
None
```

Entonces, ¿por qué `list.remove(elemento)` devuelve None?

Comment: Estás demasiado acostumbrado a `pandas` :-) Usando pandas las operaciones raramente actúan directamente sobre el dataframe, sino que retornan un nuevo dataframe dejando el original como estaba y típicamente reasignas ese resultado a la misma variable, tal como estabas haciendo tú. En cambio el método `remove` de las listas python actúan directamente sobre la lista en cuestión y no retornan nada, por lo que típicamente no se reasigna el resultado a ninguna otra variable. Simplemente `lista.remove(elemento)` ya deja la `lista` cambiada.

Comment: Podrias haberlo googleado ...

Comment: @CandidMoe una pregunta aquí puede acabar siendo el primer resultado de un consulta de google en el futuro

Comment: La parte que no entiendo es esta: "I am an MSc by research postgraduate in AI". No me calza.

Comment: @CandidMoe No sé cómo responder a eso.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica. Supongo que para trabajar en AI es requisito dominar al menos un lenguaje de programación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`lista.remove(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) elimina el elemento `x` de la lista `lista` y siempre devuelve `None`. Por tanto, lo que hace es modificar la lista sobre la que lo aplicas, de ahí que no devuelva nada.

```
>>> arr = [1,2,3,4]
>>> arr.remove(1)
>>> arr
[2, 3, 4]
>>> arr.remove(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-405f4e3f3c32> in <module>
----> 1 arr.remove(1)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```